# Declaration in header of function in struct in C++ (easy)

Tags: c++, function, struct, header

I have 3 files, 1 main.cpp, 1 Point.cpp and 1 Point.h which is needed for my homework.
Problem: Ask fo two int-numbers, save in struct-object and output highest number first:
main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Uebung8_1.h"
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
int main(){
int z;
int r;
cout << "Enter x: " << "\n";
cin >> z;
cout << "Enter y: " << "\n";
cin >> r;
Point point;
point.x = z;
point.y = r;

if (point.simsalabim(point.x, point.y) != true){
    int h = point.y;
    point.y = point.x;
    point.x = h;
}
cout << "\n" << point.x <<"\n" << point.y;

return 0;
}
```

Point.cpp

```
struct Point{
int x;
int y;
bool simsalabim(int x, int y){
    if (x >= y){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }

}
};
```

Point.h

```
struct Point{ int x; int y; bool simsalabim(int x, int y);};
```

The code works alright without the declaration(and use) of simsalabim which should decide if x is smaller than y.
I think the problem is in the header, however keep in mind that I should use a this structure of the program and cannot completley decide how it should look like. It should look somewhat like this.
Can you help me get this work?

Thx in advance

Comment: don't declare twice struct Point, but in your Point.cpp, #include "Point.h" then define bool Point::simsalabim(int x, int y)

Comment: Looks like you want `bool simsalabim() const;` and refer to the members of the point

Answer (score 2):

I think Point.cpp should look more like

```
#include "Point.h"

bool Point::simsalabim(int x, int y){
    return x >= y;

}
```

Comment: Let's simplify: `return x >= y;`.  One line content.

Comment: No, there has to be a boolean return, sry didn't mention

Comment: @user3396265: `x >= y` _is_ "a boolean return"

Comment: there also needs to be a declaration of and y in Point.cpp

Comment: but they are not static..? they are declared in .h file

Comment: but if so, how am i supposed to write the return type of that function?
bool Point::simsalabim(...)
 And thanks yes, it should be boolean.

Comment: return type is in front of it

Comment: doesn't work debugger says: not resolved external in main
1>Uebung8_1_main.obj : error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol ""public: bool __thiscall Point::simsalabim(int,int)" (?simsalabim@Point@@QAE_NHH@Z)" in Funktion "_main".

Comment: check your linker and compiler settings

Comment: @user3396265 philippe lhardy aready mentioned the two declarations of Point in your code. That might cause the linker error, but I wonder why it compiles anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You should change `simsalabim` to:

```
struct Point{
   int x;
   int y;
   bool simsalabim(){
      return (x >= y);
   }
};
```

and change the way you call it:

```
if (point.simsalabim() != true){
    int h = point.y;
    point.y = point.x;
    point.x = h;
}
```

In Point.cpp, don't include the class declaration again. Just have the member function definition.

Point.h:

```
struct Point{
   int x;
   int y;
   bool simsalabim();
};
```

Point.cc:

```
#include "Point.h"

bool Point::simsalabim(){
   return (x >= y);
}
```

Comment: changed, similiar error:
>Uebung8_1_main.obj : error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol ""public: bool __thiscall Point::simsalabim(void)" (?simsalabim@Point@@QAE_NXZ)" in Funktion "_main".
(point to not resolved external symbol)

Comment: The content of the `if` statement could be placed into the `Point` class as `void swap_ordinates(void) {std::swap(x,y);}`

Comment: If you define the body of the function in the class (struct) definition, you can't redefine it in the separate C++ source file.